# Magento 2 - how to update customer Info?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-attribute

How to update the customer information in Magento 2 (Code to set data for customer).

Example: Update `email_backup` column of `customer_entity` table.

Comment: Within Magento or outside Magento? Which information?

Comment: I just updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `email_backup` is the custom customer attribute. We can use `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` to save the customer info.

```
/**
 * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $customerRepository;

public function __construct(

    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
)
{

    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}
```

We can save:

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);

$customer->setCustomAttribute('email_backup', $emailBackupData);
$this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```